# Connect the Cassandra container to application web container failed - Error: 202 Connecting to Node

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cassandra, dockerfile, cassandra-3.0

So, I created two docker's images and I want to connect one to which other with the docker composer. The first image is Cassandra 3.11.11 (from the official hub docker) and the other I created by myself with the tomcat version 9.0.54 and my application spring boot.

I ran the *docker-compose.ylm* below to connect the two container, where *cassandra:latest* is the cassandra's image and `centos7-tomcat9-myapp` is my app web's image.

```
version: '3'

services:
  casandra:
    image: cassandra:latest

  myapp:
    image: centos7-tomcat9-myapp 
    depends_on:
      - casandra
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_HOST=cassandra
```

I ran the command line to start the app web's image :  `docker run -it --rm --name fe3c2f120e01 -p 8888:8080 centos7-tomcat9-app` .

In the console log the spring boot show me the error below. It happened, because the myapp's container could not connect to the Cassandra's container.

> 2021-10-15 15:12:14.240  WARN 1 --- [     s0-admin-1]
> c.d.o.d.i.c.control.**ControlConnection    : [s0] Error connecting to
> Node(endPoint=127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=47889c49), trying
> next node (ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...]
> Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send
> request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)**)

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This is the nodetool status about the cassandra's image:

```
[root@GDBDEV04 cassandradb]# docker exec 552d359d177e nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.18.0.3  84.76 KiB  16      100.0%            685b6e0a-13c2-4d41-ba99-f3b0fa94477c  rack1
```

**EDIT 2**
I need to connect the Cassandra's DB image with the web application image. It is different to connect microservices. I tried to change the 127.0.0.0 (inside the cassandra.yaml) to 0.0.0.0 (only to test) and the error persist. I think something missing in my docker-compose.yml for sure. However, I did not know what.

Comment: it looks like your connecting to local network card (`127.0.0.1`) try replacing with `casandra` DNS name

Comment: Thanks for your replay, Noam. You are talking about the cassandra image name? Is it function as a DNS?

Comment: I'm referring to the address in your code (in `myapp`) used to connect to the Cassandra container

Comment: ok, I'll change. So, I'm in doubt if I configure the cassandra.yaml and copy into the cassandra image too. Do I need to change the DNS there too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that but I don't think you need to make any changes to the db container, it also looks like your environment variable for `myapp` `CASSANDRA_HOST=cassandra` uses two *s*'s while your DB service has one in its name (ca**ss**andra vs ca**s**andra), maybe change the variable to match that and it would work, if that's not used that way please add the code segment used to connect to the DB.

Comment: I understood you about (cassandra vs casandra). It is casandra. It's not my fault. I changed the ip to image name. I'm testing.

Comment: I change the myapp config to cassandra DNS, restart the containers and it show this erro:   : [s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=4a976fb5), trying next node (ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException))

Comment: The DNS already had cassandra with two s's, unless you changed the **service** name (not image name) to also include two s's I don't think it would work

Comment: Could you explain how to connect a Cassandra's container to my app web container inside the docker compose? It is my first time and some parts are obscuros to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting services to communicate with each other using docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69414878/getting-services-to-communicate-with-each-other-using-docker-compose)

Comment: I think is more simple. I changed the IP to 0.0.0.0 (only to test) in the cassandra.yaml and the error persist. I'm checking the Docker's documentation. When I'll find the answer, I share it here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the error. In my case, I need to fixed the `docker-compose.yml` file adding the Cassandra and Tomcat's ports. And in my application.properties (spring boot config file), I changed the cluster's name.

**Docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:latest
    ports:
      - "9044:9042"
  myapp:
    image: centos7-tomcat9-myapp
    ports:
      -"8086:8080"
    depends_on:
      - cassandra
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_HOST=cassandra
```

**Application.config :**

```
# CASSANDRA (CassandraProperties)
cassandra.cluster = Test Cluster 
cassandra.contactpoints=${CASSANDRA_HOST}
```

This question help me to resolve my problem: [Accessing docker container mysql databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597739/accessing-docker-container-mysql-databases)